# Fetching the value from the array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to fetch 'video_url' value from the array.I have the array

```
[field_read_link] => Array ( 
  [und] => Array ( 

     [0] => Array ( 
       [url] => http://localhost/AspireInnerWebsite/ 
       [title] => Read [attributes] => Array ( ) 
     ) 

   ) 
 ) 
 [field_perspective_image] => Array ( ) 
 [field_fb_icon] => Array ( ) 
 [field_twitter_icon] => Array ( ) 
 [field_gplus_icon] => Array ( ) 
 [field_service_line] => Array ( 
   [und] => Array ( 

     [0] => Array ( 
       [tid] => 19 
     ) 

    ) 
  ) 
  [field_category] => Array ( 
    [und] => Array ( 

      [0] => Array ( 
        [tid] => 31 
      ) 

     ) 
   ) 
   [field_perspective_menu] => Array ( 
     [und] => Array ( 

       [0] => Array ( 
         [tid] => 44 
       ) 

      ) 
    ) 
    [field_display_order] => Array ( 
      [und] => Array ( 

        [0] => Array ( 
          [value] => 1 
        ) 

       ) 
     ) 
     [field_attachment_file] => Array ( ) 
     [field_perspective_video] => Array ( 
       [und] => Array ( 

       [0] => Array ( 
         [video_url] => https://www.youtube.com/embed/vG-5jZpMIHk       
         [thumbnail_path] => public://video_embed_field_thumbnails/youtube/vG-5jZpMIHk.jpg 
         [video_data] => a:1:{s:7:"handler";s:7:"youtube";}  
         [embed_code] =>     
 [description] => ) ) ) [rdf_mapping] => Array ( [rdftype] => Array ( [0] => sioc:Item [1] => foaf:Document ) [title] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => dc:title ) ) [created] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => dc:date [1] => dc:created ) [datatype] => xsd:dateTime [callback] => date_iso8601 ) [changed] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => dc:modified ) [datatype] => xsd:dateTime [callback] => date_iso8601 ) [body] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => content:encoded ) ) [uid] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => sioc:has_creator ) [type] => rel ) [name] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => foaf:name ) ) [comment_count] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => sioc:num_replies ) [datatype] => xsd:integer ) [last_activity] => Array ( [predicates] => Array ( [0] => sioc:last_activity_date ) [datatype] => xsd:dateTime [callback] => date_iso8601 ) ) [cid] => 0 [last_comment_timestamp] => 1483523222 [last_comment_name] => [last_comment_uid] => 1 [comment_count] => 0 [name] => nivetha [picture] => 0 [data] => a:1:{s:7:"overlay";i:1;} ) ) )`
```

from that array I want to fetch 'video_url' which is in `field_perspective_video`

I have tried as

```
print_r($fields['field_perspective_video'][0]['video_url']);
```

I caught

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in line

Comment: Does that error really refer the same line as your code?

Comment: Does this work: `$fields->field_perspective_video[0]['video_url']`

Comment: yes refers the same line

Comment: Shouldn't it then be: `$fields->field_perspective_video['und'][0]['video_url']`?

Comment: tr this $fields->field_perspective_video['und'][0]['video_url'];

Answer (score 0):

It means that your `$fields` is stdClass (object) instead of array.

If it's from `json_decode`, than use `json_decode($string, true)` to decode to array instead of object.

Else try using object notation `$fields->field_perspective_video[0]->video_url`

Answer (score 0):

Its look like stdClass (object) so get like this

```
$fields->field_perspective_video['und'][0]['video_url'];
```